# Need help understanding diagram of punctured torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

The above diagram is a torus with an open triangle removed. I can understand the left side perfectly, where we identify the $a$ above with $a$ below, and identify $b$ above with $b$ below, then remove the triangle demarcated with $r$. But I don't understand the diagram on the right: why is $r$ sticking out to the boundary and what's the "hole" in the middle?

Comment: In the diagram on the right Imagine the triangle with a handle attached (like that on a coffee mug) The handle inside is hollow and if you looked at it on the other side there would be two holes (if you went in one of them you would go through the "handle" and out the other one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That thing in the middle is not a hole, it is intended to be a sketch of a 3-dimensional figure, a kind of "handle" that is rising up out of the surface of the sketch.

You can also think of the whole picture on the right by first imagining a torus standing on its side, then removing the triangle from the bottom, and then strettttccchhhing out the triangle.